# Pthread arg in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am trying to create n threads passing as argument an integer identifier. My problem is that when I read that identifier from the thread shows strange things. This is my code (simplified)

```
  th_clientes = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_clientes);
  arg_clientes = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_clientes);
  t_espera = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_clientes);

// Create the pthread
  for (cont = 0; cont < n_clientes; ++cont) {
    arg_clientes[cont] = cont;
    pthread_create(&th_clientes[cont],NULL,clientes, &arg_clientes[cont]);
  }

  // Waiting for them.
  for (cont = 0; cont < n_clientes; ++cont) {
    pthread_join(th_clientes[cont],NULL);
  }

void *clientes(void *arg){
  int id = *(int *)arg;

  printf("Cliente %d realizando compra.\n",id);

  t_espera[id] = rand() % MAX;
  sleep(t_espera[id]);

  printf("Cliente %d saliendo del despues de espera %d.\n",id, t_espera[id]);
}
```

And this is a slice of my output.

```
Cliente 90 realizando compra.
Cliente 91 realizando compra.
Cliente 92 realizando compra.
Cliente 93 realizando compra.
Cliente 94 realizando compra.
Cliente 15 realizando compra.
Cliente 32551 realizando compra.
Cliente -189507840 realizando compra.
Cliente 32551 realizando compra.
Cliente 32551 saliendo del despues de espera 0.
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you are compiling code use -Wall and -Werror to avoid these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are probably not allocating enough memory for your array of `pthread_t`s. Change:

```
th_clientes = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_clientes);
```

to:

```
th_clientes = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * n_clientes);
```